# How to format a USB or external drive in Kubuntu 12.04.01?

Tags: kubuntu, format

I am aware that similar questions have been answered before for different versions/releases of Ubuntu, but I cannot find an application to reformat a USB stick in Kubuntu 12.04.01. Right-clicking the drive in Dolphin doesn't give the format option. Is it possible on software that comes with the package, without resorting to the Terminal or GParted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Disk Utility`.

This is capable to formatting drives and manage partitions.

Comment: Have downloaded - looks like this will do - Thanks ToDo

Comment: What is the package name for this? I can only find a GNOME disk utility in Kubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04 have an application called **Disks** instead of Disk Utility. I haven't upgraded to 13.10 yet.

Answer (score 1):

On **Kubuntu 14.04**:

Run *Startup Disk Creator* and choose your USB drive in *Disk to use* list. Then press *Erase Disk* button.[image]